# Method requires concrete implementation of collection. Should I change all upstream methods to return concrete implementations?

Tags: abstract-class, implementations

I have a method `processDataAssumingLinkedHashMapInput()` that processes a `Map`. The `Map` must be a `LinkedHashMap` ordered by values. Data comes from `getStrIntMap(query)`. This method gets resultSet from SQL and puts it in a LinkedHashMap. Here is the code:

```
public void processDataAssumingLinkedHashMapInput(){
    String query = "select MYID, MYVALUE from MYTABLE order by MYVALUE";
    Map<String, Integer> map = SQLTools.getStrIntMap(query);

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : rawEntryToSortOrderMap.entrySet()) {
        //do something, assuming that values are ordered
    }
    //do more stuff
}

//SQLTools method, used by multiple other classes
public static Map<String, Integer> getStrIntMap(String query){
    Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    //ResultSet to map 
    return map;
}
```

My concern is that if someone decides to change `getStrIntMap(String query)` to `Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();` (for instance for performance reasons) it will break `processDataAssumingLinkedHashMapInput()`. I can change return type of `getStrIntMap` to concrete implementation, but than it wouldn't look good and someone will change it back to an abstract `Map`. I can create two essentially identical methods one of which returns `Map` and the other returns `LinkedHashMap`, but this would break DRY principle. I can reorder data in the beginning of `processDataAssumingLinkedHashMapInput` method, but this again violates DRY rule. What is the best practice for this case?

Comment: Is this Java? Perhaps you should see [SortedMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/SortedMap.html) and its subinterface, [NavigableMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/NavigableMap.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a little IoC.  Refactor to allow the caller to inject the map instance, which will allow other developers to use the more efficient map and allow you to use the map with the features you want.

```
public static void fillStrIntMap(String query, Map<String, Integer> map){
    //ResultSet to map 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest adding a method to the library that populates a caller-supplied empty `Map` from the supplied `query`.

Keeping things DRY, the `getStrIntMap` method would invoke this other method passing in a new `LinkedHashMap`, and returning that `Map` (as an interface, so its signature remains unchanged).

Then the caller can choose the standard `getStrIntMap` which returns the `Map` interface for loose coupling, or, the caller can choose the other passing in a `Map` of its choice so it can have clear guarantees that the map is indeed a `LinkedHashMap`, and yet, the library API never has to expose concrete types.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to create a new abstract type called OrderedMap that extends abstract Map and return that. That way the method still returns an abstraction but now it is enforced that it returns an ordered map type. Existing callers can still treat the returned object as a basic map if they want, or be confident that the returned object is ordered with the implementation protected against being idly changed to return eg HashMap.